# Trying to instantiate a class member in C++ with a variable name

Tags: c++, class

I am writing a program for class that is asking us to create a class of "book".  We are then supposed to create new instantiations of that class upon demand from the user.  I am new to C++ so I am attempting to code this out but am running into a problem.

The main problem is how do I instantiate a class with a variable if I don't know how many I will have to do ahead of time.  The user could ask to add 1 book or 1000.  I am looking at this basic code:

This is the simple code I started with.  I wanted to have an index int keep a number and have the book class I create be called by that int (0, 1, 2, etc...)  So I attempted to convert the incoming index int into a string, but I'm kind of stuck from here.

```
void addBook(int index){
    string bookName;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << index;

    book bookName;

    cout << "Enter the Books Title: ";
    cin >> bookName.title; 
}
```

But obviously this doesn't work as "bookName" is a string to the computer and not the class member I tried to create.

All of the tutorials I have seen online and in my text show the classes being instantiated with names in the code, but I just don't know how to make it variable so I can create any amount of "books" that the user might want.  Any insight on this would be appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: I recommend you read about constructors.  A constructor can take a string as an argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your type `book`, if you want to create a list of books, try using a container like `std::vector`, `std::list` or `std::deque`.

```
typedef std::vector<book> library_type;

library_type library;

book catch22("Catch 22")
library.push_back(catch22);

book haltingState("Halting State");
library.push_back(haltingState);
```

You can create books and add to the library from a loop, which sounds like what you want.

Your choice of container type will depend on the access pattern you want. For example, a `std::vector` is good if you want to add books like this and you rarely want to remove them in an arbitrary order. It's fairly straightforward to change the type later if you change your mind about this.

Comment: These solutions look like they should work.  This is for our first project though and we are only supposed to use what we have been taught so far and we have not covered vectors, lists, or queues yet.  I will dig deeper.  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt mentioned above, what you want to do is create a class called book first.  In your constructor, you can set various parameters like title, author, ID, or whatever you need.  Something like (note that the compiler knows to assign the parameters to the class member variables even if they have the same name):

```
Book(int ID, std::string name) : ID(ID), name(name)
{}
```

with your class looking something like this:

```
class Book
{

private:
int ID;
std::string name;

public:
//constructor, etc.
};
```

Also, again as mentioned, vectors are probably a good first choice unless you need some specific functionality.  For your input, try a do...while loop if the user will input at least one book.

Comment: I apologize as I am new to C++, but is the top block of code the method used to create the instance of the class?  I am a bit confused at the structure of that as we have not covered this in class yet.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is.  It's what's known as a constructor and (usually) goes in the public area of the class.  Now the part with the colon-- : ID(ID), name(name)  is called an initializer list.  Basically, all it does is assign the parameters you send it to the member variables of the class.  There are a few other benefits to using it, but that's probably better left until later.  To use it, you would just create a book object like so:

Book book(827, "How to eat cake");

This would send 827 as the ID and "How to eat cake" as the name.  Hope that helps a bit!